# I get this error when I run my code SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_client, error_description: Invalid client

Tags: python, api, spotipy

I decided to try using the SpotipyAPI just to play around with. I've set the client_id and client_secret environment variables but the error above came up when I ran the code. So I decided to use a piece of example code to see if that would run.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

lz_uri = 'spotify:artist:36QJpDe2go2KgaRleHCDTp'

spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())
results = spotify.artist_top_tracks(lz_uri)

for track in results['tracks'][:10]:
    print('track    : ' + track['name'])
    print('audio    : ' + track['preview_url'])
    print('cover art: ' + track['album']['images'][0]['url'])
    print()
```

Is there something I need to add to my code or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Fred

Comment: How are you setting you env vars? I just had this error, and it was because I'd included single quotes, which is only appropriate for linux, whereas I'm on windows.

Answer (score -1):

You first have to visit: https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications.
Make a clientId and secret.
Then refer https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/
for AUTH.